# Cannot loop mount Raspbian backup image after running raspi-config

Tags: raspbian, mount, raspi-config

I have a image backup of my expanded Raspbian SD card (by running `raspi-config`) and when trying loop mount I have `Operation not permitted` error:

```
$ fdisk -lu 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img

Disk 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img: 7969 MB, 7969177600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 968 cylinders, total 15564800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xba2edfb9

                            Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img2          122880     8447999     4162560   83  Linux

$ sudo mount -o loop,noauto,offset=4194304 /vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img /opt/rpi_20150924/boot
/vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img: Operation not permitted

$ sudo mount -o loop,noauto,offset=62914560 /vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img /opt/rpi_20150924/root
/vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img: Operation not permitted
```

Also I've tried `kpartx` with similar error:

```
$ sudo kpartx -lv /vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img
/vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img: Operation not permitted
can't set up loop
```

I am using `Ubuntu Trusty64` with `2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie` and `2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie` expanded images.

Any idea?.
Regards.

Comment: It was my fault. The `/vagrant/2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img` had not the permissions and owner to do loop-mounting. With `$ sudo chmod +x 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img` and `$ sudo chown <YourUser> 2015-09-24-raspbian-jessie-of.img` worked.